# SQL CASE statement to set column value not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that joins several tables and I am trying to create a couple of columns using case statements to determine the value (a hyper link text) that is not working as expected. I want to look at the row resulting from the joins and if a value from one of the left joins is not null, then I want to concatenate some text with the value, if it is null I will concatenate text with a different value. The query is:

```
SELECT p.*, p.id AS ppe_id, CONCAT(u.last_name, ',', u.first_name) 
    AS name, sub1.created_at AS last_inspection,
  CASE
    WHEN (sub1.created_at IS NULL AND man_date < now() - interval '1 year'  )
    THEN 'over-due'
    WHEN (sub1.created_at IS NULL AND man_date < now() - interval '11 months'  )
    THEN 'due'
    WHEN sub1.created_at < now() - interval '11 months'
    THEN 'due'
    WHEN sub1.created_at < now() - interval '1 year'
    THEN 'over-due'
    ELSE 'none'
  END
    AS inspection_due, 
  CASE 
    WHEN now() > p.man_date + interval '10 years' 
    THEN 'over-due' 
    WHEN now() > p.man_date + interval '119 months' 
    THEN 'due' 
    ELSE 'none' 
  END 
  AS expiring,
  CASE 
    WHEN cl_sub.ppe_id IS NOT NULL
    THEN '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/' || cl_sub.id || '">Cleaning</a>'
    WHEN cl_sub.ppe_id IS NULL
    THEN '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="/ppes/'|| cl_sub.ppe_id || '/cleanings/new">Clean</a>'
  END
  AS cleaning_button,
  CASE
    WHEN r_sub.ppe_id IS NOT NULL
    THEN '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/' || r_sub.id || '">Repairing</a>'
    WHEN r_sub.ppe_id IS NULL
    THEN'<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="/ppes/' || r_sub.ppe_id || '/repairs/new">Repair</a>'
  END
  AS repair_button     
FROM  ppes p
  JOIN users u
  ON p.user_id = u.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ppe_id, id FROM cleanings cl WHERE cleaning_date IS NULL ) AS cl_sub 
  ON p.id = cl_sub.ppe_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ppe_id, id FROM repairs r WHERE completed IS NULL ) AS r_sub
  ON p.id = r_sub.ppe_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t.ppe_id, t.created_at
      FROM inspections t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ppe_id, max(created_at) as LastInsp
          FROM inspections
          GROUP BY ppe_id ) tm
          ON t.ppe_id = tm.ppe_id AND t.created_at = tm.LastInsp
      WHERE (t.advanced = true AND t.passed = true) order by t.ppe_id) AS sub1
ON sub1.ppe_id = p.id;
```

The issue is that even though the two joins produce the desired effect, i.e. they either come up with an id for either of the sub query or they come up with null, I only get output from the first half of each case statement:

```
CASE 
WHEN cl_sub.ppe_id IS NOT NULL
THEN '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/' || cl_sub.id || '">Cleaning</a>'
WHEN cl_sub.ppe_id IS NULL
THEN '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="/ppes/'|| cl_sub.ppe_id || '/cleanings/new">Clean</a>'
END
AS cleaning_button,
CASE
WHEN r_sub.ppe_id IS NOT NULL
THEN '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/' || r_sub.id || '">Repairing</a>'
WHEN r_sub.ppe_id IS NULL
THEN'<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="/ppes/' || r_sub.ppe_id || '/repairs/new">Repair</a>'
END
AS repair_button
```

If I query the table for those fields it shows that the cases where the cleanings table or the repairs table returned an ID in the join, it puts in the desired value, but otherwise it leaves it blank instead of putting in the second value from the case statement:

```
ppe_development=# select id, cleaning_button, repair_button from test_view_ppes  order by cleaning_button, repair_button;
 id  |                         cleaning_button                          |                          repair_button                          
-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 126 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/13">Cleaning</a> | 
  13 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/24">Cleaning</a> | 
 115 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/27">Cleaning</a> | 
 113 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/5">Cleaning</a>  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/3">Repairing</a>
 114 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/6">Cleaning</a>  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/14">Repairing</a>
  53 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/8">Cleaning</a>  | 
   1 | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/cleanings/9">Cleaning</a>  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/13">Repairing</a>
  54 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/16">Repairing</a>
  57 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/17">Repairing</a>
  56 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/22">Repairing</a>
  58 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/25">Repairing</a>
 118 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/26">Repairing</a>
   7 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/28">Repairing</a>
  15 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/30">Repairing</a>
  11 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/32">Repairing</a>
 120 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/33">Repairing</a>
 123 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/5">Repairing</a>
 116 |                                                                  | <a class="btn btn-xs btn-back" href="/repairs/7">Repairing</a>
  78 |                                                                  |
```

ppes table:

```
id | serial |  man_date  | category |         created_at         |         updated_at         | user_id | note | size | manufacturer | active | cost | cbrn_rated 
---+--------+------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------+--------+------+------------
12 | 10007  | 2017-01-25 | jackets  | 2017-01-25 17:40:10.652715 | 2017-04-11 00:46:58.154629 |       5 |      |      |              | t      | 0.00 | 
18 | 10013  | 2017-01-25 | jackets  | 2017-01-25 17:40:10.663324 | 2017-04-11 00:46:58.187638 |       6 |      |      |              | t      | 0.00 | 
20 | 10015  | 2017-01-25 | gloves   | 2017-01-25 17:40:10.66659  | 2017-04-11 00:46:58.199712 |       6 |      |      |              | t      | 0.00 | 
24 | 10019  | 2017-01-25 | jackets  | 2017-01-25 17:40:10.673236 | 2017-04-11 00:46:58.228069 |       8 |      |      |              | t      | 0.00 | 
26 | 10021  | 2017-01-25 | gloves   | 2017-01-25 17:40:10.67665  | 2017-04-11 00:46:58.239997 |       8 |      |      |              | t      | 0.00 |
```

cleanings table:

```
id | cleaning_date | user_id | ppe_id |           notes            |         created_at         |         updated_at         | failed_inspection 
---+---------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------
 5 |               |       1 |    113 | 1                          | 2017-04-01 21:11:28.882502 | 2017-04-01 21:11:28.882502 | f
 6 |               |       1 |    114 | 2                          | 2017-04-01 21:11:41.068899 | 2017-04-01 21:11:41.068899 | f
 8 |               |       1 |     53 | Bamboo                     | 2017-04-07 19:36:17.48159  | 2017-04-07 19:36:17.48159  | f
13 |               |       1 |    126 | testing new routing        | 2017-06-25 20:38:16.813986 | 2017-06-25 20:38:16.813986 | f
```

repairs table:

```
id | order_date | completed | user_id | ppe_id |        notes         |         created_at         |         updated_at         | failed_inspection | cost 
---+------------+-----------+---------+--------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+------
 5 |            |           |       1 |    123 | testing photo upload | 2017-04-03 19:20:37.175447 | 2017-04-03 19:20:37.175447 | f                 | 0.00
 7 |            |           |       1 |    116 | testing large photo. | 2017-04-03 19:56:12.391366 | 2017-04-03 19:56:12.391366 | f                 | 0.00
13 |            |           |       1 |      1 | acl test             | 2017-04-04 07:35:59.974909 | 2017-04-04 07:35:59.974909 | f                 | 0.00
14 |            |           |       1 |    114 | rover1 upload\r     +| 2017-04-04 07:57:16.602674 | 2017-04-04 07:58:50.505527 | f                 | 0.00
16 |            |           |       1 |     54 |                      | 2017-04-04 08:53:29.394382 | 2017-04-04 08:53:29.394382 | f                 | 0.00

id | passed | user_id | ppe_id |         created_at         | advanced 
---+--------+---------+--------+----------------------------+----------
22 | f      |       7 |      6 | 2017-06-20 17:39:37.253423 | f
34 | f      |       1 |      4 | 2017-06-22 20:07:24.214546 | f
23 | f      |       9 |     20 | 2017-06-20 20:00:02.506964 | f
26 | t      |       5 |     42 | 2017-06-20 20:07:23.207904 | f
24 | t      |      10 |      4 | 2017-06-20 20:01:28.161158 | f
```

Comment: Without seeing your table data I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Wait, if `r_sub.ppe_id IS NULL` then the concatenation will become `NULL`, too...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto ah! yes that would be the case. If I try to concatenate things with null do they become null?

Comment: Almost every operation in SQL returns `NULL` if any of its arguments is `NULL`. (Exception being EG `COALESCE()`)... (`NULL` interpreted as "unknown value"...)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto You nailed it. In the case of the ppe_id being null I can get the same id from p.id. I changed it to p.id and it works perfect. SQL is not my strength so this was driving me crazy. If you want to make an answer for it I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `r_sub.ppe_id IS NULL` then the concatenation will become `NULL`, too...

As almost every function and operation in **SQL** returns `NULL` if any of its arguments is `NULL`. (NULL interpreted as "unknown value"...)