# SQL Server : group by consecutive

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable 
(
    HevEvenementID INT,
    HjvNumeSequJour INT,
    HteTypeEvenID INT
);

INSERT INTO yourtable 
VALUES (12074, 1, 66), (12074, 2, 66), (12074, 3, 5),
       (12074, 4, 7), (12074, 5, 17), (12074, 6, 17),
       (12074, 7, 17), (12074, 8, 17), (12074, 9, 17), (12074, 10, 5)
```

I need to group by consecutive `HteTypeEvenID`. Right now I am doing this:

```
SELECT
    HevEvenementID,
    MAX(HjvNumeSequJour) AS HjvNumeSequJour,
    HteTypeEvenID
FROM
    (SELECT
         HevEvenementID,
         HjvNumeSequJour,
         HteTypeEvenID
     FROM
         yourtable y) AS s 
GROUP BY
    HevEvenementID, HteTypeEvenID
ORDER BY
    HevEvenementID,HjvNumeSequJour, HteTypeEvenID
```

which returns this:

```
HevEvenementID  HjvNumeSequJour HteTypeEvenID
---------------------------------------------
12074            2              66
12074            4               7
12074            9              17
12074           10               5
```

I need to group by consecutive `HteTypeEvenID`, to get this result:

```
HevEvenementID  HjvNumeSequJour HteTypeEvenID
----------------------------------------------
12074           2               66
12074           3                5
12074           4                7
12074           9               17
12074           10               5
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: consecutive HteTypeEvenID?   They are all he same.   VTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this with aggregation and difference of row numbers:

```
select HevEvenementID, HteTypeEvenID,
       max(HjvNumeSequJour)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by HevEvenementID order by HjvNumeSequJour) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by HevEvenementID, HteTypeEvenID order by HjvNumeSequJour) as seqnum_2
      from yourtable t
     ) t
group by HevEvenementID, HteTypeEvenID, (seqnum_1 - seqnum_2)
order by max(HjvNumeSequJour);
```

I think the best way to understand how this works is by staring at the results of the subquery.  You will see how the difference between the two values defines the groups of adjacent values.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's not exactly what I need but it's getting there.. I need the result to be ordered by hjvNumeSequ, your query is ordered by HteTypeEvenID

Comment: @MelodieGauthier . . . No.  The original query was not ordered by anything, because it didn't have an `order by` clause.  I added the `order by`.